# moveCursor(start, end) raise exception ''QTextCursor' has no attribute keepAnchor"

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

A find text dialog form is run from a mainwindow where the actual text is in a QTextEdit field. After finding the text, self.moveCursor(start, end) results in an exception "QTextCursor has no attribute 'keepAnchor'

I am making a test editor following the publication by Peter Goldsborough "Building a text editor with PyQt: Part 3# integrated with four dock windows showing MySql queries.

```
class Main(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__( parent)
        self.filename = ""
        self.qdb = self.check_connection()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        ........
        self.text = QTextEdit()
        self.text.setTabStopWidth(33)
        self.text.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.cursorPosition)
        ......
     def initToolBar(self)
        self toolBar = self.addToolBar("Options")
        self.findAction = QAction(QIcon("icons/find.png","Find and Replace", self)
        self.findAction.triggered.connect(find.Find(self).show)
        .........................................

class Find(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.lastMatch = None
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        findButton = QPushButton("Find", self)
        findButton.clicked.connect(self.find)
        replaceButton = QPushButton("Replace", self)
        replaceButton.clicked.connect(self.replace)
        allButton = QPushButton("Replace All")
        allButton.clicked.connect(self.replaceAll)

        self.normalRadio = QRadioButton("Normal", self)
        self.normalRadio.toggled.connect(self.normalMode)
        self.regexRadio = QRadioButton("Regex", self)
        self.regexRadio.toggled.connect(self.regexMode)

        self.findField = QTextEdit(self)
        self.findField.resize(250,50)
        self.replaceField = QTextEdit(self)
        self.replaceField.resize(250, 50)

        optionsLabel = QLabel("Options: ", self)

        self.caseSen = QCheckBox("Case Sensitive", self)
        self.wholeWords = QCheckBox("Whole Words", self)

        spacer = QWidget(self)
        spacer.setFixedSize(0,10)

        layout = QGridLayout()

        layout.addWidget(self.findField, 1, 0, 1, 4)
        layout.addWidget(self.normalRadio,2,2)
        layout.addWidget(self.regexRadio, 2, 3)
        layout.addWidget(findButton,2, 0,1, 2)

        layout.addWidget(self.replaceField, 3, 0, 1, 4)
        layout.addWidget(replaceButton,4, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(allButton, 4, 2, 1, 2)

        layout.addWidget(spacer, 5, 0)

        layout.addWidget(optionsLabel, 6, 0)

        layout.addWidget(self.caseSen,6, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.wholeWords, 6, 2)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 360, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle("Find And Replace")
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.normalRadio.setChecked(True)

    def find(self):
        text = self.parent.text.toPlainText()
        query = self.findField.toPlainText()

        if self.wholeWords.isChecked():
            query = r'\W' + query + r'\W'

        flags = 0 if self.caseSen.isChecked() else re.I
        pattern = re.compile(query, flags)
        start = self.lastMatch.start() + 1 if self.lastMatch else 0
        self.lastMatch = pattern.search(text, start)
        if self.lastMatch:
            try:
                start = self.lastMatch.start()
                end = self.lastMatch.end()
                if self.wholeWords.isChecked():
                    start += 1
                    end -=1
                self.moveCursor(start, end)
            except Exception as err:
                   print(err)

        else:
            self.parent.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
```

I expected the found text to be highlighted. I try several changes in the super of the Find class always with the same exception. When y tried "type(self) I got wrappertype class ext.find.Find insted o QDialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own mistake. In the move method I misspelled keepAnchor with a lowercase 'k' instead of a capital 'K'
Sorry for the inconvenience!!